# What is the proper way to check if a string contains a set of words in regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string, let's say, `jkdfkskjak some random string containing a desired word`

I want to check if the given string has a word from a set of words, say `{word1, word2, word3}` in latex.

I can easily do it in Java, but I want to achieve it using regex. I am very new to regular expressions.

Comment: Do you need to know *which* word from the set of words it contains?

Comment: If you don't care about which word is contained, try [`.*(word1|word2|word3).*`](https://regex101.com/r/Ql7evk/1)  and if the line matches, it contains one of those words

Comment: Keep in mind that regular expressions are quite inefficient at searching multiple words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand the complete context like what kind of text you have or what kind of words will this be but I can offer you a easy solution the literal way programmatically you can generate this regex **(dormammu|bargain)** and then search this in text like this "**dormammu I come to bargain**". I have no clue about latex but I think that is not your question.

For more information you can tinker with it at [regex101][1].

If you are having trouble understanding it [regexone][2] this is the place to go. For beginners its a good start.

[1]: http://regex101.com   [2]: https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 2):

if you want only to recognise the words as part of a word, then use:

```
(word1|word2|...|wordn)
```

(see [first demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBYKKJ/1))

if you want them to appear as isolated words, then

```
\b(word1|word2|...|wordn)\b
```

should be the answer (see [second demo](https://regex101.com/r/SBYKKJ/2))